# DNS CNAME - SSL-certificate issue

Tags: domain-name-system, email, ssl

I have obtained an SSL certificate by Thawte for domain.com
Now my infrastructure changed due to heavy load
I have

- mx.domain.com as SMTP relay
- storage.domain.com as Mail-Storage
- and domain.com pointing at Web-Server

Every server is hosted on another dedicated/virtual server with individual IP.
I do not want to put the Web-Server on the Mail-Storage for security reasons but I do want to use my SSL-Certificate for the Mail-Storage(POP3S/IMAPS). Is that possible or how do I solve that issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the ssl certificate needs to match the domain name exactly.

So either you're going to need to get those other ssl certificates created and signed, otherwise it may be worth looking at a wildcard ssl certificate which will work with multiple subdomains

Comment: What about pointing domain.com to the MailStorage ... and relaying port 80 to Web-Server? Would that work =D?

Comment: Well, you could use mod_rewrite, or whatever, to point domain.com/storage to storage.domain.com and so on. That would work, because the FQDN would be the same.